# How to create "My status" using php and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

As title mentioned, how to create a status bar(like facebook or twitter). User can type in what is he doing now? I believe its using AJAX, but then how to store to database? (I am new to AJAX)

For example:
User type in "I am eating now", then click the "update" button, then It will update automatically to the status field, displaying the text you type in and the time you type in. When you roll-over, it will display menu like, "edit", "clear" etc..

Is there any tutorials or sample code to do it??

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://nettuts.com/tutorials/php/twitter-emulation-using-mootools-12-and-php/) is an article for you which uses mootools.

> How to emulate Twitter's
>   functionality. Using PHP, MySQL, and
>   MooTools javascript, you can implement
>   a Twitter-like status system in no
>   time.